# Search a SharePoint 2010 List

Tags: list, search, filter

Using out of the box functionality, I added a search web part and my list view below it on a page. Connected the two and I am able to search the list as needed. The problem is that the list already exists on the page prior to searching, and the search merely filters out the results.

I don't want the users to view the full list before they conduct their search though. Is there a way to not have the list already in view on the page and only have the results appear once a search has been completed? Is there some code I could use to provide a search box and then only display the results once the search is executed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default search value for that page to a value that can't be true.